# what can happen if i add too much powder to my kitten formula?

Tags: cats, feeding

I accidentally been adding 1 table spoon of powder and 2 tablespoons of water to my kitten formula, instead of 2 1/2.

My kitten has only pooped once in the 3 days we’ve had him.

What can i do to make it up? Can there be some bad consequences?

My kitten is 2 weeks old.

Answer (score 1):

Any update on this? I noticed you posted it about a month ago.

My first thought is to check the jar/container and see if there is any warning for the cat getting too much powder. However, I’m not sure how much of a difference  1/2 a tablespoon of water would make. I think there would be more of a concern if you were actually giving the kitten too much or too little powder, because the powder has the nutritional value/level the kitten needs for the time being. I’ve never had a super young kitten, so I’m not sure if you are allowed to give them plain water. I would just try to find a way to keep him better hydrated if he is constipated.

My second thought is I’ve heard that really young kittens need stimulated to help go to the bathroom.

There is a great YouTube channel with tons of information on kittens. The channel is Kitten Lady. She tells all about kitten development, growth, how-tos, etc. I would recommend seeing if her video on bottle feeding would help.

Hopefully your kitty is doing better now!

Comment: Be mindful promoting a youtube channel in your answers.